# Can I put Kensington lock in my hand luggage?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, hand-luggage

I frequently fly around Europe only with a hand luggage. Recently I bought a Kensington lock for my laptop which I usually take with me. The lock did not cause any problems at the airports in Edinburgh, Bremen, Athens, Copenhagen and Stansted. However, it almost got confiscated at the security gate at the Gdansk airport (Poland). It took me half an hour to convince the guard that I do not intend to harm anyone with that. I was told that although there are numerous hand luggage restrictions, the guard has a right to make a subjective decision whether or not to confiscate certain items.

My question is - did anyone hear about similar incidents with Kensington locks? Are there any specific rules or guidlines that I can refer to to defend my right to take the lock with me? Or maybe kensington locks should not be taken on board at all? And how do the restrictions differ around the globe?

Comment: Problem in Poland is that until recently security screening in international airports was handled by the Border Guard. But since 2013 it's no longer their duty, thus airports had to hire private security contractors. Their training (or lack of thereof) leaves much to be desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no particular restriction against as far as I have known and seen. I was once made to show it to the security inspector but I have traveled with one and similar items through dozens of countries without any issues. One other time, it was a audio-cable extension which got an extra look by security. They let it in anyway and I suspect it looks exactly the same as the lock wire in the x-ray.